# Online motor inductance measurement at different rotor angle

Tags: motor, inductor, passive-networks, wheatstone-bridge, lcr

I wanted to measure the inductance of PMSM at different rotor angles. I'm familiar with the offline methods of measuring motor inductance but would like to measure a motor's inductance while it's running online at low speed. So I'm wondering if anyone can show me how to measure.